# Confused by Flow coverage over an array of a defined type

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I have a type that I've explicitly defined called `Product`:

```
// types.js

export type Product = {
  id: number,
  name: string
}
```

Here is the code for my component that uses this type:

```
import type { Product } from './types'

type Props = {
  products: Product[]
}

const MyComponent = ({ products }: Props) => (
  <ul>
    {products.map( (product: Product) => 
      <li key={product.id}>{product.name}</li>
    )}
  </ul>
)
```

What's strange is that when running `yarn flow coverage path/to/this/component --color`, `flow` tells me that the file is not 100% covered, highlighting `id` in `product.id` and `name` in `product.name` as the culprits.

If I instead define the type of `product` inline like this:

```
products.map( (product: { id: number, name: string }) => ...)
```

The file is then 100% covered. Why is this happening? My assumption is that, using the `Product` type, I should be covered here.

EDIT: It might be worth noting that when I remove the type from the `product` like so:

```
products.map( product => ... )
```

The coverage is obviously less, but this time instead of just highlighting `id` and `name`, the `flow` cli highlights `product.id` and `product.name`.

EDIT 2: User error. I never added `// @flow` to the `types.js` file!

Whoops :)

Answer (score 0):

I never but a `// @flow` comment at the top of my `types.js` file. That solved the issue.